# Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference error when all other dependent projects compile

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013

Please watch this screencast as a video would say a thousand pictures:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/84476328/ShareX/2013-10/2013-10-26_06-49-48.mp4

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 and attempted to compile a perfectly working Visual Studio 2012 solution.

Start-up project is ShareX and I can compile all other dependent projects as shown in the screencast. When it gets to compiling the main project, it fails.

I have no idea how this could happen.

All projects are on .NET Framework 3.5. 
Entire solution was fully compilable in Visual Studio 2012. 
I have removed references and re-added them to no avail.

Appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem with Nuget. The following source code changes in all the csproj files fixed it. I am linking it for future reference just in case another person stumbles across the same problem: 
https://code.google.com/p/sharex/source/detail?r=742

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this problem as well (Win7, VS2012, C#, WinForms).  My solution includes a personal "framework" DLL project that I  reference directly, the main EXE project and a UnitTests project.  I admit I moved the directory structure around a bit and hand edited the relative paths of the solution in Notepad++.  A few builds/hours later I was getting hundreds of errors stemming from the framework DLL project being mysteriously missing.

Here's what fixed the situation for me:

1. Remove the offending project(s) from the solution.

   - Save the solution.
   - Add project(s) back to solution.
   - Update the project-project dependencies
   - Update references to the solution's project(s).
   - Save
   - Clean
   - Verify build order
   - Verify configuration manager
   - Rebuild solution